# Performance of Swift vs Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am just comparing the performance of [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_%28Apple_programming_language%29) and [Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C). For that, I am using NSDate to measure the time taken, but I am getting a big difference between Swift and Objective-C. I just ran an empty `for` loop 100,000 times. Here is my code,

In Objective-C,

```
NSDate * start = [NSDate date];

for (int i=0; i<=100000; i++) {

}

NSDate * end = [NSDate date];

double timeTaken = [end timeIntervalSinceDate:start] * 1000;
```

timeTaken is 0.24 milliseconds

In Swift,

```
var start = NSDate()

    for i in 0...100000

    {

    }

    var end = NSDate()

    var timeTaken = end.timeIntervalSinceDate(start) * 1000
```

`timeTaken` is 74 milliseconds in Swift, which is a big difference when compared to Objective-C.

Am I doing anything wrong here in the measurement?

Comment: You might want to do it over something like 1 million iterations as well.

Comment: I started work on a demo app to test performance [here](https://github.com/cezarywojcik/CWSortTester). In my findings thus far (using sorts), it looks like even with optimizations turned on, Swift is around 3-4 times slower.

Comment: lol. Im not sure iterating over an empty code block being slower tells anyone anything :D Unless this is a common use case for an application. How many sprites per second can you render?

Comment: You should test performance doing some sort of operation, for instance I would try to enumerate an array using enumerations method. Are you using simulator or device?

Comment: Swift code will [run much faster by enabling -Ofast mode](https://twitter.com/nadavrot/status/474659423441678336) to remove runtime safety checks.

Answer (score 18):

What you are doing is pure nonsense. It doesn't matter what the performance of this loop is, because it doesn't happen in real code. The essential difference is that in Swift, the loop will do overflow checks at each step which are a required side effect due to the language definition. In Objective-C, that's not the case.

At the very least you need to do code that does actually meaningful things.

I've done some *real* tests, and the results were: 1. Speed of Swift and plain C for low-level operations are comparable. 2. When on overflow happens, Swift will kill the program so you can notice the overflow, while C and Objective-C will silently give you nonsense results. Try this:

```
var i: Int = 0
var s: Double = 0.0

for (i in 1 .. 10_000_000_000) { s += Double (i * i) }
```

Swift will crash. (Anyone who thinks that's bad hasn't got a clue about programming). The same thing in Objective-C will produce a nonsense result. Replace the loop with

```
for (i in 1 .. 10_000_000_000) { s += Double (i) * Double (i) }
```

and both run at comparable speed.

Comment: I don't say what i am doing is nonsense or not. I know this is not a common use case. Since there was a big difference, my actual question is "Am i doing anything wrong in the measurement?" as i am new to both objective c and swift.

Comment: So what is your conclusion about the large disparity in the OP? "Your measurement isn't a real-life case" isn't really an answer to the question.

Comment: `Swift will crash. (Anyone who thinks that's bad hasn't got a clue about programming).` I'd say that anyone who makes such sweeping generalisations knows little about programming outside their own immediate field of experience... :-)

Comment: "Swift will crash. (Anyone who thinks that's bad hasn't got a clue about programming)." Actually it's the opposite... Swift shouldn't just "crash". It should stop running producing detailed error messages that helps you track down the problem. This is probably what happens anyway, in which case you should rephrase that sentence because the word "crash" doesn't generally refer to a behaviour that provides many helpful diagnostics by default (e.g. "segmentation fault").

Comment: "The essential difference is that in Swift, the loop will do overflow checks at each step which are a required side effect due to the language definition."   Could an optimizer possibly recognize that these checks aren't required as well, and thus really optimizes the loop into void?

Comment: -Ofast setting is what you're looking for here — this disables the checks for integer overflows and array indexing overflows

Comment: Can someone explain why the latter is better? What's wrong with `Double(i*i)`

Comment: @ByronS `Double(i*i)` calculates `Int` by multiplying two `Int` values and then converts that product into a `Double`. The problem is that 10 billion times 10 billion results in a number that is too large to be represented by an `Int`.

Answer (score 8):

I did some tests with sort function which used native Swift array and Swift string compared to Objective C mutable array and NSString.

Function was ordering 1000 strings and it performed ~ milion string comparisons and it shuffled the array.

Results were the following:

- Objective C (using primitive integers and booleans): 0.32 seconds
- Objective C (using NSNumber for integers and booleans): 0.45 seconds
- Swift in debug mode: 13 seconds :)
- Swift with Optimization level (Fastest [-O]): 1.32 seconds
- Swift with Optimization level (Fastest, Unchecked [-Ofast]): 0.67 seconds

Seems in fastest mode Swift came pretty close to Objective C but it is still not faster as Apple claim(ed).

This is sort code I used:

Swift:

```
var strFile = String.stringWithContentsOfFile("1000strings.txt", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
var strings:String[] = strFile!.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
var startDate = NSDate()
var shouldLoopAgain = true
var numberOfLoops = 0
while shouldLoopAgain {
    shouldLoopAgain = false
    ++numberOfLoops
    for var i = 0; i < strings.count-1; ++i {
        if (strings[i] > strings[i+1]) {
            let temp = strings[i]
            strings[i] = strings[i+1]
            strings[i+1] = temp;
            if !shouldLoopAgain {
                shouldLoopAgain = true
            }
        }
    }
}
var time = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(startDate)
```

Objective C with primitive boolean and integers

```
NSMutableArray *strings = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[strFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
BOOL shouldLoopAgain = YES;
int numberOfLoops = 0;
while (shouldLoopAgain) {
    shouldLoopAgain = NO;
    ++numberOfLoops;
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.count-1; ++i) {
        if ([strings[i] compare:strings[i+1]] == NSOrderedDescending) {
            NSString *temp = strings[i];
            strings[i] = strings[i+1];
            strings[i+1] = temp;
            if (!shouldLoopAgain) {
                shouldLoopAgain = YES;
            }
        }
    }
}

NSTimeInterval time = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
```

Objective C with NSNumber for boolean and integers

```
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
NSNumber *shouldLoopAgain = @YES;
NSNumber *numberOfLoops = @(0);
while ([shouldLoopAgain boolValue]) {
    shouldLoopAgain = @NO;
    numberOfLoops = @([numberOfLoops intValue]+1);
    for (NSNumber *i = 0; [i intValue] < strings.count-1; i = @([i intValue]+1)) {
        if ([strings[[i intValue]] compare:strings[[i intValue]+1]] == NSOrderedDescending) {
            NSString *temp = strings[[i intValue]];
            strings[[i intValue]] = strings[[i intValue]+1];
            strings[[i intValue]+1] = temp;
            if (![shouldLoopAgain boolValue]) {
                shouldLoopAgain = @YES;
            }
        }
    }
}
NSTimeInterval time = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
```

Answer (score 5):

By default, the compiler optimisation level is set to `None [-Onone]` in debug mode...

Changing this to `Fastest [-O]` (like release) gives the following results:

[image]

Comment: There is even faster level if you set to 'Fastest, Unchecked [-0fast]' ... this one came pretty close to Objective C speed but still slower.

Comment: -O was faster anyway.. Objective C took ~0.24ms and Swift took ~0.07ms

Answer (score 2):

Try compiling with optimizations enabled. If that doesn't change the situation, file a bug with Apple. Swift is still in beta, so there may be rough spots.

Comment: Performance issue is a bug ? I think it works as expected but just slower than expected ?

Comment: Slower than expected absolutely counts as a bug!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that as of today you can run these tests and determine with any certainty whether Swift 1.0 is faster or slower than Objective-C.  The entire Swift language is still under development, syntax and the way aspects of the language are implemented are changing.  This is clear from the changes in the language between Xcode 6 Betas 2 and 3, and if you look on the Apple Dev Forums you can see the Apple guy's who are working on the language clearly saying that stuff isn't complete or optimised and that it won't be until the Swift 1.0 release, which should happen alongside the public release of Xcode 6.

So, I'm not saying there isn't value in doing these tests right now, but until Swift 1.0 is finalised we can't say anything conclusive about final performance.

Answer (score 1):

Take look at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/242816/how-can-swift-be-so-much-faster-than-objective-c-in-these-comparisons and http://www.splasmata.com/?p=2798 tutorial, might be you  can get answer. But main point it that Swift language is still in beta. And also apple does/might not confidently announce that Swift is more faster than objective-c in all the cases. Apple said to us base on average performance. My view is that If in some cases obj-c is faster than swift, it doesn't mean that all over performance of swift is slower. We just give more time to Apple for it.