# Swift vs Objective-C Fibonacci Sequence Speed Comparison

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I have a problem. I want to know which one is indeed faster(Swift or Objective-C) because I would like to choose a faster/better one when I start developing an app. According to many sources(For example Apple's WWDC, or http://www.jessesquires.com/apples-to-apples-part-two/), Swift is suppose to be faster.

I just wrote a simple recursive fibonacci sequence program in both Swift and Objective-C.

However, when I run fib(35) on the simulator, I get surprising results:

**Objective-C Result:**

:::fib::::9227465:::duration:::0.122813 seconds

**Swift Result**

:::fib::::9227465 :::duration:::0.606831073760986 seconds

Now, I even ran the Swift version in all Swift Compiler Optimization level(for Debug), which is None, Fastest, Fastest-Unchecked. I also play around with the Code Generation Optimization Level to None, Fast....Fastest Aggressive Optimization.
However all Swift results are something close to 0.6 milliseconds

Now the last thing I can think of is may be, I am comparing an Apple to Orange?
Do you guys see anything I am missing here? Is there anything else I have to turn on(other than Optimization levels for Swfit Compiler & Apple LLVM Code Generation) to make Swift programs run faster?

Any suggestions or comments are welcome and appreciated ! ^^ !

**Objective-C Version**

```
-(int)fib:(int)num{
    if (num == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (num == 1) {
        return 1;
    }    
    return [self fib:num - 1] + [self fib:num - 2];
}
```

**Swift Version**

```
func fib(num: Int) -> Int{
    if(num == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(num == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    return fib(num - 1) + fib(num - 2);
}
```

**Objective-C Time Measurement**

```
  NSTimeInterval start = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
  int result = [self fib:35];
  NSTimeInterval end = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

  NSTimeInterval duration = end - start;
  NSLog(@":::fib::::%d:::duration:::%f",result,duration);
```

**Swift Time Measurement**

```
var start = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970;
let result = fib(35);
var end = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970;

var duration = end - start;
println(":::fib::::\(result) :::duration:::\(duration)");
```

Comment: how do you measure the time?

Comment: @BryanChen I just updated the question with Time Measurement Codes, I am using NSDate in both Swift and Objective-C

Comment: NSDate is not good for benchmark. and >1 ms is just too small, you better to repeat the test for many times so they both takes at least a second to run. Also, your code will only show the difference between dynamic dispatch vs static dispatch.

Comment: (apart from that, your method : 3, as a parameter, gives 2; 5 gives 5; 8 gives 21. What is the explanation for the result you are supposed to get?)

Comment: @BryanChen I actually repeated the experiment more than 15 times each on Swift and Objective-C and I get similar results.

Comment: I mean something like `start = ...; for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) fib(35); end = ...`

Comment: You were under the impression that the name "Swift" was somehow indicative of performance??

Comment: By the way, see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/24077639

Comment: @Rob Nice catch, you are correct,  the measurement for time is in seconds. ^^ . thanks

Comment: @Paul the expected results are the fibonacci sequence: 1 1 2 5 8 13 21 ...

Comment: @Steve correct, it is the index in the sequence.

Answer (score 8):

Lot of things to consider when deciding which of the two programming languages are faster. I did a couple of benchmarks (https://github.com/vsco/swift-benchmarks) between Swift and Objective-C and I found that in certain cases Swift was faster and in other cases Objective-C was faster. For example, using struct objects in Swift will offer tremendous performance gains if you need to operate over a large amount of data. In contrast, using non-struct objects made Swift significantly slower than it's Objective-C counterparts.

Also how you use certain features in Swift is very crucial to how well it will perform. Take this function for example:

```
class func shuffleGenericObjects<T>(inout array:[T]) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
        let currentObject: T = array[i]
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random()) % array.count
        let randomObject: T = array[randomIndex]

        array[i] = randomObject;
        array[randomIndex] = currentObject
    }
}
```

Sure it works great for minimizing repetitive code, but when I executed this method over 1 million Int objects, it took roughly 32 seconds to finish. As oppose to the non-generic implementation, which only took 0.181 seconds.

I also recommend not to use `NSDate` functions for benchmarking in Swift. I came across a few bugs that caused `NSDate` to return incorrect times. It's much better to put your benchmarks in an `XCTestCase` and use the `measureBlock()` function.

Comment: Excellent example. By the way, this shuffle is [not even distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle#Potential_sources_of_bias). Better, use `let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count - i))) + i`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Essentially my non generic implementation takes an `[Int]` instead of a `[T]`. You can check out my different implementations with benchmarks [here](https://github.com/vsco/swift-benchmarks). The `[Int]` implementation is also faster than it's `NSMutableArray` version. The performance improvement occurs whenever you're able to use struct objects which I'm sure you know that Int and String are. The downside to using struct objects is that you cannot bridge them back to Objective-C. As far as I know Int and String are the only structs that can bridge back to Objective-C.

Comment: @fyell FYI: I tried the code with latest Xcode beta Version 6.3 (6D532l) and it completed in 0.04s (generic version, 1mil integers, release build, target OS X). Swift is still being actively improved and the comparisons against Objective C continue to improve, sometimes dramatically.

Comment: @MirekE It certainly is significantly faster in beta! Very impressed with how much Swift performance has improved. Check out my blog post with some of my Swift 1.2 benchmarks https://medium.com/@fielgood/swift-1-1-swift-1-2-and-objective-c-a-performance-case-study-d86f7a333e2a

Answer (score 5):

The choice of Fibonacci as your benchmark is a little ironic, because in WWDC 2014 video [Advanced Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=404) they use the Fibonacci sequence as an example of how you can write a generic `memoize` function that is several orders of magnitude faster.

```
func memoize<T: Hashable, U>(body: ((T)->U, T) -> U) -> (T)->U {
    var memo = [T: U]()
    var result: ((T)->U)!
    result = { x in
        if let q = memo[x] { return q }
        let r = body(result, x)
        memo[x] = r
        return r
    }
    return result
}
```

Where you can then:

```
let fib = memoize { fib, x in x < 2 ? x : fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2) }

let result = fib(35)
```

Now, clearly, it's unfair to compare this to a non-optimized Objective-C recursive Fibonacci function, because this will leave it in the dust. I'm not even sure I agree with all of the WWDC's conclusions regarding the merits of the Swift generic `memoize` implementation. But the performance improvement is startling.

---

There are plenty of patterns where a naive translation of Objective-C code will result in slower Swift implementations. In particular, far more dramatic than your example where the Swift code was a little slower, I've been startled by simple situations in which it's quite easy to write a routine in Swift that looks logically very similar (or even more elegant), but is really much, much slower (or at least prior to the app developer refactoring the Swift implementation a bit).

Bottom line, I would personally hesitate to draw any simple conclusions of Swift is faster than Objective-C, or vice versa. I suspect that there are some algorithms/applications where Swift is faster and others where it is not.

Furthermore, you say that the regarding the choice of programming language that you "would like to choose a faster/better one". I would contest that the "faster" language is always "better" one (otherwise, we'd all still be writing assembly code). Often, the choice of language is less the raw computational efficiency of the code, and more the effectiveness of the developer. We should all chose the language in which we can write the most robust code, do so in the most cost-efficient manner, writing code that is most easily maintained in the future, and  deliver a superlative user experience.

Whether that language is Swift or Objective-C is a matter of opinion and is not for this forum.

Comment: +1 Esp for the last two paragraphs. In nowadays performance is not the big problem of application development. If it is, it is more a problem of structure than of a single computation.

Comment: You write about non-optimized functions, do you maybe know some good sources where you can learn how to improve your coding into this direction? So more pro stuff, no simple beginner tutorials

Comment: At that point, I think you've moving out of the realm of simple web tutorials and into the world of university classes and text books that delve into the world of algorithm theory and design. I just searched for "algorithm" in Amazon's books, and there are a bunch of promising texts right at the top. I'd be inclined to get one that balances theory (e.g. "big oh" notation, NP complete problems, etc.) with more practical considerations (e.g. analysis and comparison of different sort algorithms, optimization techniques such as hashes and caches, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good, but you can't generalize the speediness of a programming language on one situation like that.  In Apple's Keynote last year, they said "complex object sort" was faster in Swift.  There are probably a couple things faster in Objective-C, but generally, Swift is supposed to be the faster language.

Comment: OP want to see Swift is actually faster. this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: What do you mean? The OP is currently testing a specific method and trying to generalize the performance of an entire language. There are so many other factors that should go into this decision other than just which language is able to calculate a Fibonacci sequence faster. It's like trying to pick the best football player and just looking at their 40 time.